# MAC XAMPP Permission Issues

Tags: macos, permission, big-sur

XAMPP is installed in the Applications folder on MAC, whenever I create a new directory for a website and deploy the files I get an error related to permission.

For example:

> Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laravelproject/ExampleFile.php

Same applies to Wordpress when installing a plugin

> Installation failed: Could not create directory.

I used the below command:

```
sudo chown -R root:admin /Applications/XAMPP/
```

Also

```
sudo chown -R daemon:daemon /Applications/XAMPP/
```

None of both has worked.

I've set admin group and everyone group to Read & Write privilege this didn't resolve the issue.

Whenever creating a new directory inside `htdocs` by default it doesn't have admin group added and also everyone group is set to No access I have to manually manage this always.

Your suggestions are highly appreciated

Comment: What OS? /Applications is no longer a 'user' folder in Big Sur. *edit* D'oh, I just spotted the tag… that's your reason, I'm afraid I don't know the fix...

Comment: @Tetsujin Users can still applications to /Applications on Big Sur.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using XAMPP instead of XAMPP-VM (see https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_stackman.html)?

Comment: @nohillside not sure but probably it uses more resources while the native is easier and simpler

Comment: Why do see it necessary to manage access rights within htdocs yourself? Is there a need to give access to admin/everyone?